# Property database not loaded when MemoryLimited is activated

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I have discovered that the Forge viewer's property database does not load when the MemoryLimited extension is active on mobile browsers (v 7.*). Because of this, the properties manager panel does not work and neither does viewer.getProperties(). Is this the intended behavior? And if so, is there a way to force loading of the property database when MemoryLimited is active?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's expected: the property database will not load when a memory limit is set. Please refer to [this documentation](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/viewer_basics/memory-limit/). You can load the extension and get more details:

```
viewer.getExtension('Autodesk.MemoryLimited').getMemoryInfo()
```